# How to write quotient_graph result to file

Tags: python, networkx

Here is a MWE to create the "issue"

```py
>>> A = nx.complete_bipartite_graph(2, 3)
>>> same_neighbors = lambda u, v: (u not in A[v] and v not in A[u] and A[u] == A[v])
>>> B = nx.quotient_graph(A, same_neighbors)
>>> B.nodes()
NodeView((frozenset({0, 1}), frozenset({2, 3, 4})))
>>> B[frozenset({0, 1})]
AtlasView({frozenset({2, 3, 4}): {'weight': 6}})
>>> B.nodes[frozenset({0, 1})]
{'graph': <networkx.classes.graph.Graph object at 0x12b066e80>, 'nnodes': 2, 'nedges': 0, 'density': 0}
```

I believe this `graph` attribute on the node is specifying the subgraph which this node comes from in the original graph, but I'm not sure. If someone could verify that would be nice.

Either way though, this `graph` attribute prevents me from using the `nx.write_graphml` function because subgraphs cannot be used as data formats. In particular it raises

```
networkx.exception.NetworkXError: GraphML writer does not support <class 'networkx.classes.graph.Graph'> as data values.
```

Now I don't actually need the subgraph in the `graphml` file, so just dropping that data is probably the best way for me to get the graph written to a file. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I believe this graph attribute on the node is specifying the subgraph which this node comes from in the original graph, but I'm not sure. If someone could verify that would be nice.

**Yes, you are right** in assuming that the `graph` attribute is actually specifying the subgraph based on the original graph. It is mentioned in the documentation for quotient graph . Check out the description of `node_data`, you will find that:

```
node_data (function) – This function takes one argument, B, a set of
nodes in G, and must return a dictionary representing the node data
attributes to set on the node representing B in the quotient graph. If
None, the following node attributes will be set:

- graph, the subgraph of the graph G that this block represents,
- nnodes, the number of nodes in this block,
- nedges, the number of edges within this block,
- density, the density of the subgraph of G that this block represents.
```

You can also check out the subgraph yourself, by typing

```
for node in B.nodes():
    print("Information for subgraph ", node)
    print(B.nodes[node]['graph'].nodes())

# Output:
# Information for subgraph  frozenset({0, 1})
# Nodes are  [0, 1]
# Information for subgraph  frozenset({2, 3, 4})
# Nodes are  [2, 3, 4]
```

> Now I don't actually need the subgraph in the graphml file, so just
>   dropping that data is probably the best way for me to get the graph
>   written to a file. What is the best way to do this?

You can simply create a new graph and add only the nodes and edges, and discard any other data. (Again, you are right in assuming that this information is irrelevant for writing data in GraphML format as you only need the nodes and edges).

Let's check the EdgeView of the Quotient graph, before going further:

```
B.edges(data=True)
# EdgeDataView([(frozenset({0, 1}), frozenset({2, 3, 4}), {'weight': 6})])
```

Notice, how the `data` for the edge is dictionary with `weight` as key. This info. will be useful in the subsequent code.

Now, create a new graph, and add the edges directly from the quotient graph.

```
H = nx.Graph()

# Here B is the quotient graph
for u,v,d in B.edges(data=True):
    # Notice how the weight is assigned to the new graph
    H.add_edge(u, v, weight=d['weight'])
```

If you want to verify that the new graph has the same structure, you can check it out using [nx.is_isomorphic](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.isomorphism.is_isomorphic.html#networkx.algorithms.isomorphism.is_isomorphic)

```
nx.is_isomorphic(H, B)
# True
```

Now you can simply write your graph into GraphML format

```
nx.readwrite.graphml.write_graphml(H, "my_graph.graphml")
```

For more information, you can check out [this Google Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1a62PpGD065sPneDGM19jusPXoVQ-HYN-), with the above working code.

**References:**

- [NetworkX - Quotient Graph](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.minors.quotient_graph.html#networkx.algorithms.minors.quotient_graph)
- [write_graphml](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/generated/networkx.readwrite.graphml.write_graphml.html#networkx.readwrite.graphml.write_graphml)
- [NetworkX - is_isomorphic](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.isomorphism.is_isomorphic.html#networkx.algorithms.isomorphism.is_isomorphic)